# Query on why some of my comment flags are declined

Tags: discussion

On more than one occasion I have raised a flag on a comment where a user has posted a question, and then immediately added extra information in a comment, without anyone else prompting them.

I flag the comment citing it should be an edit to the question. The flag is declined and I find that the question has then been edited, to include the information in the comment. But the comment has not necessarily been removed.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Thought I'd make a mention for the record: Your flagging history is phenomenal. You produce a lot of flags with a really high level of accuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little prompting from Ghanima I think I figured out what happened with the most recent incident (referred to by Jacobm001 above).

I happened across the comment and moved its content into the main question body *without ever seeing your flag* - I hit the erroneous comment while skimming through new posts. After that point I'm a little fuzzy on the details - I don't remember explicitly dismissing your flag, but the system says I did. I'm going to do a little poking about and take a look at where the 'delete comment' and 'dismiss flag' buttons are in relation to each other - it's possible that I've fat-fingered the wrong button, dismissing your flag rather than deleting the comment.

In summary: Looks like this was my fault! My apologies for that. I'll do my best to pay a little more attention to where I'm landing my clicks when I'm shunting things around in future.

Comment: Apology accepted, we are only human and mistakes are bound to happen. Thank you for clearing the issue up. I asked the question as I wanted to check that my flagging activity is useful and not generating unnecessary work and to clarify if there was a different action I could have taken.

Comment: Please keep flagging things! You're a valuable asset here. :)

Comment: @DarthVader, I'll contact CM to have mod elections scheduled immediately. [*Apology accepted, Captain Goobering*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttPwA8hitoY)

Answer (score 4):

I went through the last couple months of your flagging history, and I only saw one instance of the particular issue you brought up. Looking at the post history, I agree, that your flag should have been accepted, especially since the edit was done after the flag was declined.

I can't speak for the moderator who declined your flag, but my guess is that it was an accident.